# Project is not creating using cordova platform add android

Tags: android

I am trying to make phone gap sample program and I download all required software,but during creation it shows following errors in command prompt.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must set ANDROID_HOME var in CMD:

```
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\\your_android_sdk_path
```

and next

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```

Comment: how to do it? D:\android-sdk-windows this is my sdk path so exaplain in details.

Comment: than add this in command line: 

set ANDROID_HOME=D:\\android-sdk-windows

Comment: its normal. try make phonegap again.